# Xcode how to make more dots in a page controller

Tags: xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have a page view controller with 10 pages, the sliding effect works perfect. But I have only 3 dots at the bottom so that every user thinks there are only 3 pages to slide. How can change the page controller to see more dots?

Comment: and this is not the problem of xcode. You should remove this tag and add objective, cocoa instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIPageControl *pc = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
[pc setNumberOfPages:100];//this line is responsible for number of dots
[self.view addSubview:pc];
```